# SQL REGEXP search ignoring '.'

Tags: sql, regex, search, sqlyog

I am trying to do a REGEXP search on everything in a database and I am trying to get all the .cxx file types. My current search is like

```
SELECT * FROM sourcefile 
WHERE idowner IS NULL AND name REGEXP '.cxx'
```

And the current output is something like

```
filecxx.txt 
file.cxx  
test.cxx
```

However I want to to only show the .cxx files not just the ones with cxx in their name so expected output would be

```
file.cxx  
test.cxx
```

Comment: Use `AND name LIKE '%.cxx'` or `AND name REGEXP '[.]cxx$'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`REGEXP` may return a partial match, it does not require a full string match.

Thus, if you need to match a string ending with `.cxx`, you need

```
AND name REGEXP '[.]cxx$'
```

where `[.]` matches a literal `.` (if used as is, it matches any char) and `$` matches the end of string.

Or simply use `LIKE`

```
AND name LIKE '%.cxx'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your output is correct since you are using a wildcard `.`, this means any character and then `cxx`, that's why you also match `ecxx`.

You have to escape the dot, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM sourcefile 
WHERE idowner IS NULL AND name REGEXP '[.]cxx'
```